# Geometrical meaning - Derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The area of a trapezoid with basis $a$ and $b$, and height $h$ equals to $S = \frac{1}{2} (a+b) h$. Find $ \frac{\partial S}{\partial a}, \frac{\partial S}{\partial b}, \frac{\partial S}{\partial h} $ and, using a drawing , determine their geometrial meaning.

I have no idea of the geometrical meaning of the partial derivatives, in this case. Can you give me a help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}$, for example, is the rate of change of the area when $a$ is changing, when the other side, $b$, and height, $h$, *are kept constant*.